# pycharm print the variable value automatically

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a newbie of python and I got a problem with pycharm.
Such as the picture below, I type in `username = input ("username=")` without print.However the run result still shows the value of variable. It's so confusing.

[image]

Comment: I believe that is just printing the return value of an assignment operator.  A pretty typical feature.  Though I apologize if I have misconstrued your question...

Answer (score 0):

At this version, don't had this confusing problem.

```
PyCharm 2017.1.5
Build #PY-171.4694.67, built on July 4, 2017
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your time. should be caused by the setting of remote interpreter, no other effect for using temporarily.